# Do I need a thread lock for an assign statement in python?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have below two methods. The data is an `dict` instance. The program is running in a multi-thread mode. Do I need to place a `threading.lock` on the data instance in order for thread-safe? I understand that if there are multiple statements in each `write` and `read` method, a lock is required for the blocks but whether is it needed if it is a single assignment? Is it possible causing partial update on `data` instance?

```
def write(self, data):
    self.data = data

def read(self):
    return data
```